# Meteorite Matroska / MKV Repair Engine works, but has anyone made something better since 2011?

Tags: video-editing, vlc, mkv

[image: project meteorite]

Project Meteorite was halted in 2011, and while the software works fine, the interface is drag-and-drop only, often crashes after big files, and could benefit from further development.

http://www.mkvrepair.com/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/meteorite/

**Has anyone created a new MKV seek repair engine**, or forked this project and made it better by adding batch processing and other enhancements? I can't find anything online except older projects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a fork: https://github.com/abarnert/meteorite

Unfortunately, no released any binary files of this Meteorite forked.

I personally wanted to compile to EXE that source-codes of this fork.

Downloaded master.zip from GitHub.
Downloaded CodeBlocks & MinGW (GCC version 4.9.2).
Downloaded wxWidgets-3.1.0.

I spent a lot of time for compile. Unfortunately, CodeBlocks always give several errors while I click to Build/compile.

If you can compile, can you share the EXE file?

UPDATE: Maybe this version can compile https://github.com/cbielow/meteorite